# How-to ensure multiple collections have the same item count using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

Is there any great way to ensure multiple collections have the same item count using LINQ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool sameLength = (collections.Select(c => c.Count())
                              .Distinct()
                              .Take(2)   // Optional (for optimization).
                              .Count()) == 1;
```

or:

```
bool sameLength = !collections.Select(c => c.Count()).Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
```

It works by finding checking the length of each collection and keeping track of unique values. Having one distinct count is OK, but if there are two (or more) distinct counts then all the collections aren't the same length so the result is false.

---

Update: If the collections have different types you can use a non-generic interface as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284841/how-to-ensure-multiple-collections-have-the-same-item-count-using-linq/5285093#5285093).

```
var collections = new List<ICollection> { a, b, c, d };
```

Comment: collections ? you mean an aggregate of all my collections ?

Comment: my collections are not of the same types : List<double>, List<MyItem>, etc. But i need to compare counts of all lists

Comment: @Mark, can you elaborate "collections" ?

Comment: I would add Take(2) after Distinct() as there is no need to count more than two.

Comment: @Mark Byers: i don't understand how do you get that "collections" variable. Can you elaborate in your answer how to you declare this ?

Comment: @Yoann: collections is assumed to be an IEnumerable (i.e. a list) of collections, where each item is a collection that you want to compare the item count of - so it represents a "collection of collections"

Comment: First option is really hard to read. I wouldn't want to maintain this code. Second one would better be `.Distinct().Count() == 1`. We'd lose some performance but improve readability.

Comment: @gaearon: Isn't your improvement to the second one basically the just first one again?

Comment: You're almost right, it's the same as cutting `.Take(2)` from first. I just feel those tiny optimizations hurt readability.

Comment: @gaearon: My original answer didn't include the Take(2) - if you read the comments you can see I only added this after people commenting suggested it. I now have made a compromise by pointing out that this line is optional. If performance is more critical then use it - if readability is more important then omit it.

Answer (score 2):

Check if

```
collection1.Count() == collection2.Count()
```

Beware that this enumerates the collection. If the collection is expensive to enumerate (like LINQ2SQL) or mutates the state (updates some data and/or logging) there is no great way at all using LINQ.

Comment: `Count` doesn't *always* enumerate the collection. For `ICollection`, as far as I remember, it uses `Count` property internally.

Answer (score 2):

If all your collections implement `ICollection` interface, you can put them into single `List<ICollection>` and then apply the Mark's method.

```
var a = new List<int>();
var b = new List<double>();
var c = new List<float>();
var d = new List<string>();

var collections = new List<ICollection> { a, b, c, d };
var sameLength = collections.Select(c => c.Count).Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Comment: Great. I would only argue that this code would better be with `.Distinct().Count() == 1`. We'd lose some performance but improve readability. `.Skip(1).Any()` is kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: @gaearon: True. As we are using `ICollection.Count` there should not be any meaningful performance impact if the number of collections is small. Things are different when working with some unknown collections that are known to implement only `IEnumerable<>` interface. I will change the code.